# Can anyone explain what does this dollar sign in here mean?

Tags: java, android, xml

`<fragment android:name="com.example.android.quakereport.SettingsActivity$EarthquakePreferenceFragment" . . . </fragment>`
Here, the (SettingActivity) and the (EarthquakePreferenceFragment) are any classes in java.

Can anyone tell me what is the use if $ in here ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means an inner static class. In your example it would be as next:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
  .... other activity code ....


   // Inner class

   public static class EarthquakePreferenceFragment extends Fragment {

     .......
   }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. It is in the same format you wrote.
Thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 4):

It means `EarthquakePreferenceFragment` is an inner class of `SettingsActivity`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Does that inner(EarthquakePreferenceFragment) class will be called automatically from the SettingActivity class when i remove that android:name attribute the code doesnot work ??
Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.